# Read file with strange separations in python

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to automate a process. But one of the files have a very strange separation.

[The columns are separated by spaces, but some rows have more spaces then others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlUup.png)

Any one have idea how solve this.

Thank a lot! :D

Comment: Do You mean the `board` column?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd make sure that this is not an artefact of the interface you use for viewing the file, because some of them might actually just display tabs like this.
You can split the file using regular expressions on multiple spaces.

```
import re

for line in file:
    fields = re.split("\s+", line)
```